# Do functions have a performance penalty in GLSL?

Tags: android, iphone, opengl-es, glsl

Do functions have a performance penalty in GLSL (especially on iOS and Android implementations)?

Under performance penalty I imply additional time necessary for function invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how the function is used. If it's written in a way that it can be inlined by the compiler, then there's no penality. If however the function can not be inlined, then of course there's a bit of overhead. However a simple texture access is already more expensive than a function call, so I wouldn't bother about it. GLSL compilers, fortunately, have become quite capable.

Comment: Can you please explain what does "If it's written in a way that it can be inlined by the compiler" mean?